# java script: onblur() working in opera but not in mozilla

Tags: javascript

This is my code :

```
<script>
function showVehical(type){
var element = document.getElementById('TotalCoach');
element.onblur="myfunction(type);";
}

function myfunction(type){
alert(type);
}

</script>

<HTML>
<body>
<input type="text" name="totalNumberOfCoach" id="TotalCoach" value="1"/>
</body>
</HTML>
```

The above code is working fine on opera but not in mozilla onblur() not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a javascript library (like jQuery), to eliminate discrepancies between browsers.

Comment: This too, you could use $(document).ready(function(){}); To ensure that the TotalCoach element existed when the javascript ran. Also $("#TotalCoach").blur(function(){myfunction(type);}); to have a more compatible blur event.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you call showVehical()? It needs to be after the TotalCoach input field is ready. This code works for me:

```
<script>
function showVehical(type){
var element = document.getElementById('TotalCoach');
element.onblur=function() {myfunction(type);};
}

function myfunction(type){
alert(type);
}
</script>
<HTML>
<body>
<input type="text" name="totalNumberOfCoach" id="TotalCoach" value="1"/>
<script>
showVehical("a");
</script>
</body>
</HTML>
```